# Elasticsearch not analyzed and lowercase

Tags: elasticsearch, lowercase

I'm trying to make a field lowercase and not analyzed in Elasticsearch 5+ in order to search for strings with spaces in lowercase (them being indexed in mixed case)
Before Elasticsearch v5 we could use an analyzer like this one to accomplish it:

```
  "settings":{
     "index":{
        "analysis":{
           "analyzer":{
              "analyzer_keyword":{
                 "tokenizer":"keyword",
                 "filter":"lowercase"
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

This however doesn't work for me right now. And I believe the problem to be that "string" is deprecated and automatically converted to either keyword or text.
Anyone here know how to accomplish this? I thought about adding a "fields" tag to my mapping along the lines of:

```
  "fields": {
    "lowercase": {
      "type": "string"
       **somehow convert to lowercase**
    }
  }
```

This would make working with it slightly more challenging and I have no idea how to convert it to lowercase either.

Below you'll find a test setup which reproduces my exact problem.

**create index:**

```
{
  "settings":{
     "index":{
        "analysis":{
           "analyzer":{
              "analyzer_keyword":{
                 "tokenizer":"keyword",
                 "filter":"lowercase"
              }
           }
        }
     }
  },
  "mappings":{
     "test":{
        "properties":{
           "name":{
              "analyzer":"analyzer_keyword",
              "type":"string"
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

**Add a test record:**

```
 {
    "name": "city test"
  }
```

Query that should match:

```
{
    "size": 20,
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "bool": {
                    "should": [{
                        "wildcard": {
                            "name": "*city t*"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you searching on the `name` field while the field in your mapping is called `title`? Also why not simply declaring its type as `"type":"text"` instead? And finally, how `amsterdam t` is supposed to match `city test`?

Comment: Let me update the examples, I have copied the wrong thingies :) My apologies.

if I declare it as text it doesn't work with spaces.

Comment: What I basically want is to have a string like "City Test" and match that on "city test". that is all.

Comment: Yes, but what if you declare it as `text` with your keyword/lowercase analyzer?

Comment: It ignores that completely. It will still not match spaces and behave as if I didn't place the analyzer.

Comment: Oh I know, it's because the `analysis` section needs to go directly under `settings` and not `settings > index`. Wipe your index and try again...

Comment: That works flawlessly! Thanks mate! (if you want, post an answer I'll accept it!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating your index, you need to make sure that the `analysis` section is right under the `settings` section and not inside the `settings > index` section otherwise it won't work.

Then you also need to use the `text` data type for your field instead of the `string` one. Wipe your index, do that and it will work.

```
{
  "settings":{
        "analysis":{
           "analyzer":{
              "analyzer_keyword":{
                 "tokenizer":"keyword",
                 "filter":"lowercase"
              }
           }
        }
  },
  "mappings":{
     "test":{
        "properties":{
           "name":{
              "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword",
              "type": "text"
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work in ES 1.7.1, I mean it doesn't support `type` `text`

Comment: @sunkuet02 in 1.7.1 you can use `"type": "string"` instead, it's equivalent

Comment: I have done this, but I have failed to be succeeded to fulfill my requirement : https://stackoverflow.com/q/44648327/2315473